# Displaying data from database to modal CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm making an Computer Laboratory Monitoring System using CI framework.
I want to display the detail of the selected item in my list but i got an error says :

> Message: Trying to get property 'invent_id' of non-object

Here's my code view code

```
    <?php if(!empty($value)): ?>
    <?php foreach($value as $post ): ?>
        <tr>
                <td data-field="id"><?php echo $post->invent_id;?></td>
                <td data-field="id"><?php echo $post->name;?></td>
                <td data-field="id"><?php echo $post->type;?></td>
                <td data-field="id"><?php echo $post->stock;?></td>
            <td> 
            <button name="view" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal<?php echo $post->invent_id; ?>" class="btn btn-info view_data"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">
            </span></button>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span></a></td>

            <?php $this->load->view('Modal/view_inventory_detail', $post);  ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <tr>
                <td>No Records Found</td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My controller

```
    function inventory_list(){

    $value['value']         = $this->Admin_Model->get_inventory();

    $this->load->view('HeadtoFoot/header');

    $this->load->view('Admin/inventory/list',$value);

    $this->load->View('HeadtoFoot/footer');


}
```

And My Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal<?php echo $post->invent_id; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Item Details</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <!-- Details Goes Here -->
                </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I have the query used in `get_inventory()`

Answer (score 0):

The **Trying to get property of non-object** error in CI generally happens when running a query. I would guess the error is happening in the call to the model:

`$this->Admin_Model->get_inventory()`